# How to access multiple opened excel files in Python

Tags: python, excel

I have three excel files on a shared server. They are opened by three different users. How can I read the data from these excel files, without making them close it or throwing an error to them?

Is it possible with Python or any other programming language, or should I seek other avenues?

Comment: Start by finding an Excel lib that you can install with pip. The examples should contain your use case.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything special. Any Python library should be able to read the excel file without the users having to close it. Now if you want to make changes to the excel files after reading the data then you'll run into problems. You can still do it, but the changes wouldn't be seen by those who already have the file open, and as soon as they save the file they would be overwriting any changes you tried to make. But if you just want to read the data, they don't have to close the file for you to do that.

Comment: You will need the users to close them, if you plan on writing to the files, otherwise if you want to open them as read-only, you will need to copy the files from the remote server either on-disk or into memory.

Comment: @OneCricketeer you are right:  `pip install pandas` THEN `df = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')` THEN `df`